# firebug script debugger not showing current page javascript sometimes

Tags: list, firebug, reload

When i load the page i want to debug. i click the firebug icon and firebug appears ok. i click the script tab and i am asked to "Reload to see all sources". I do the reload and most of the time i see the inline javascript and the html of the currently loaded page. There are times when i go through this process and i DONT see the current page html and inline javascript, instead, i see most of the other javascript FILES associated with the loaded page. i cannot figure out how to get my currently loaded page and its inline javascript to appear again. i clear the cache, restart firefox, reset options? 
 Also, when i click the list to see the javascript files and pages, I dont see my currently loaded page listed. But, when i AM able to "Reload to see all sources" and my current page html and inline javascript appears, THEN it is included in the list. 
Not sure what i need to do here?

thanks for any help

Comment: OK, i think i found one answer - my current page had an error in its inline javascript. Once I fixed the error and called up firebug and reloaded the current page, i could see my current page show up in the script debugger list and panel. If there is anyway i can configure the firebug debugger to DEBUG my current page when i initially call it up in the firebug debugger with an inline error, that would be great. Instead, it just dosnt display it and dosnt tell you why. Funny, it displays so many messages and options for debugging everything else. Must be some configuration i am not seeing.

Comment: Found my answer. Next time my current page does not display, or I have issues calling up the current page, i need to "Ctrl/Shift/J". When i did this, the Error console appeared and inside of it I could see the error clearly spelled out. Thanks firebug!!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
1 - Press f12 to open firebug console.
2 - Goto firebug menu at top left of firebug console.
3 - Goto Options -> Reset All Firebug Options.
```